# Drone's motion is unstable with ROS topics

Tags: ros, ardrone2.0

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

```
import rospy  
import time

from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from std_msgs.msg import String 
from std_msgs.msg import Empty 
from ardrone_autonomy.msg import Navdata



COMMAND_PERIOD = 1000


class AutonomousFlight():
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = ""
        rospy.init_node('forward', anonymous=False)
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(10)
        self.pubTakeoff = rospy.Publisher("ardrone/takeoff",Empty, queue_size=10)
        self.pubLand = rospy.Publisher("ardrone/land",Empty, queue_size=10)
        self.pubCommand = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel',Twist, queue_size=10)
        self.command = Twist()
        #self.commandTimer = rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(COMMAND_PERIOD/1000.0),self.SendCommand)
        self.state_change_time = rospy.Time.now()    
        rospy.on_shutdown(self.SendLand)

    def SendTakeOff(self):
        self.pubTakeoff.publish(Empty()) 
        self.rate.sleep()

    def SendLand(self):
        self.pubLand.publish(Empty())


    def SetCommand(self, linear_x, linear_y, linear_z, angular_x, angular_y, angular_z):
        self.command.linear.x = linear_x
        self.command.linear.y = linear_y
        self.command.linear.z = linear_z
        self.command.angular.x = angular_x
        self.command.angular.y = angular_y
        self.command.angular.z = angular_z
        self.pubCommand.publish(self.command)
        self.rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    try: 
        i = 0
        uav = AutonomousFlight()

        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            uav.SendTakeOff()
            if i <= 30 :
                uav.SetCommand(0,0,1,0,0,0)
                i+=1
            elif i<=60 :
                uav.SetCommand(0,0,0,0,0,0)
                i+=1
            else:
                uav.SendLand()

    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

I need to just takeoff, go up and go to hover mode,

```
uav.SendTakeOff()
            if i <= 30 :
                uav.SetCommand(0,0,1,0,0,0)
                i+=1
            elif i<=60 :
                uav.SetCommand(0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

after take off, this code makes the drone go to little back and some random motion and going up and going to hover mode. How can I fix this ? and the motion is stable sometimes

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265362/drone%27s-motion-is-unstable-with-ros-topics/) by [Kathir](https://answers.ros.org/users/28902/kathir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-07-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-03**:
You should post the question here if you want users on this site to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should take a look at the [`ardrone_autonomy` documentation](https://ardrone-autonomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to check see how to check what state your drone is in. I remember from using this (about a year ago) that when you're sending twist commands you're in the `Flying` state which I don't believe uses the drone's own stabilization control loops.

According to the [docs](https://ardrone-autonomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html), in order to have the drone drone in "auto-hover" mode you need to send a `geometry_msgs/Twist` message with all zeros except for non-zero values on the `angular.x` and `angular.y` components. This shows that you really can't expect stability during takeoff using `geometry_msgs/Twist` messages without implementing some kind of control loop.

If you're just having the drone takeoff then you should use the `ardrone/land` service and you should see better behavior.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0